# Why conditionally cast to an interface type fails in dart?

Tags: dart, casting

I have this very simple code

```
abstract class Bar {
  String name;
}
class Base {}
class Foo extends Base implements Bar {
  String name;
}


void main() {
  final Base foo = Foo();
  if (foo is Bar) {
    foo.name = 'a';
  }
  print(foo);
}
```

Where I want to set an object's property if it implements an interface. But running it fails with error

```
The setter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'Base'.
```

Looks like either the if statement doesn't cast foo to Bar, or Bar doesn't have the setter?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart *type promotion* (the thing that allows you to use a variable at a different type than the one it was declared at) does not handle this case.

A variable in Dart only has *one* type associated with it at any time.
When you do an `x is SomeType` test, the variable *might* be promoted to `SomeType`, if the compiler can convince itself that it's perfectly safe to treat the variable as the new type.

One part of this rule is that type promotion only allows you to promote to a *subtype* of the current type. That way, you it's a strict promotion, you don't lose information that you already have.

Here you try to promote from `Base` to `Bar`, but `Bar` is not a subtype of `Base`.
So, promotion would have to choose either `Base` or `Bar` as the *one* type. Either choice will throw away information (or would if `Base` had any useful members which can't be called on a `Bar`), so the compiler has to make a choice.
And so it keeps the type of `foo` as `Base`.

You can do the test is `if (foo is Foo)` instead, because `Foo` is a subtype of `Base` and has a `name` setter.

Or you can make a promotable variable and promote that:

```
  Object obj = foo;
  if (obj is Bar) foo.name = "a";
```

This works because promoting from `Object` to `Bar` is a promotion to a subtype.

Or you can cast:

```
  if (obj is Bar) (obj as Bar).foo = "a";
```

That looks somewhat redundant. Hopefully a compiler can convince itself that there is no reason to do the second check.